# Django setting initial dropdown value from current instance?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

I am trying to set the initial choices in a dropdown, on profile edit for selecting `Business` type. But I want the dropdown to already have the current instance' selections already chosen. But I just cant figure out how to render this on the frontend. I heard of a select option that jinja template offers, to do this?

I will take a code snippet from my app,

```
def edit_profile(request):

    request_user = request.user


# FOR SENDING USER TO SERVER
    if request.method == 'POST':
        template_name = 'business/profile_view.html'
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']

        business = request.POST.getlist('business_type', '')
        if business == '':
            pass


    try:
        user_obj = Account.objects.get(email=request.user)

        """ Loop over business types and assign to user """
        user_obj.business.clear()
        for _business in business:
            user_obj.business.add(_business)

        return redirect('/auth/edit_profile/')
    except Exception as e:
        message = {"message": "Profile edit ERROR"}
        return render(request, template_name, message)

# FOR SERVER TO USER
if request.method == 'GET':
    template_name = 'business/profile_view.html'
    context = dict()
    user_obj = Account.objects.get(email=request.user)

    context['business_type'] = user_obj.business



    if request.path == '/auth/edit_profile/':
        return render(request, template_name, context)
    elif request.path == '/auth/edit_profile_edit/':
        return render(request, 'business/profile_edit.html', context)
```

And my Template

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="business_type" multiple="multiple"title="Select a category">
             {% for business in business_types %}
                 <option value="{{ business.id }}">{{ business.name }}</option>
             {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: I think you should double check your indentation in your code above, some of it seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Ah yeah, its prob from reddit, I manually spaced when I was copy/pasting ha!

Answer (score 0):

You can add "selected" to your views context:

```
context['selected'] = business  # or however you are identifying the selected
```

then in the html you can add the selected tag with an `ifequal` statement:

```
{% for business in business_types %}
     <option {% if ifequal business.name selected.name %}selected{% endif %} 
         value="{{ business.id }}">{{ business.name }} </option>
{% endfor %}
```

or if the context is a list, then you can use `{% if business in selected_businesses %}`

```
{% for business in business_types %}
     <option {% if business in selected_businesses %}selected{% endif %} 
         value="{{ business.id }}">{{ business.name }} </option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah it is a list. in my `Account` model I have an m2m to a `Business` model, which is just a model with business types that are in my dropdown menu. I would think that adding this would work. `context['selected'] = user_obj.business.name`

Where does that `selected_businesses` come from in the template? Is that a built in jinja namespace?

Comment: selected_businesses was just an example variable name, it looks like you are retrieving the list here: `business = request.POST.getlist('business_type', '')`, so it could look something like `selected_businesses = request.POST.getlist('business_type', '')`

Comment: So right now, on GET request, context['business_type'] = user_obj.business Maybe I need to convert that to a list, and get the values. Because that context will have to provide multiple values, for ex. an `Account` can choose to be multiple types of businesses.

Comment: Right, you'll likely want a list since you're allowing multiple selections.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into [Django's forms system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/). It does a lot of the work of setting up forms, rendering widgets, and even validating your data for you. You can also send forms with the current instance already filled in